# Does the Node.js "request" library support an async-iterable response stream?

Tags: node.js, async-await, stream, async-iterator

I'm somewhat new to Node.js libraries and I'm trying figure how to use async iteration over an HTTP response stream.  My overall goal is to read a large response stream and process it as chunks arrive, currently via a generator function.  I cannot store the entire response in memory for processing.

I'm using the `request` library to execute the HTTP request as follows.

```
const request = require("request");

// contrived chunk-by-chunk stream processing 
async function* getChunks(stream) {
  for await (const chunk of stream) {
    yield chunk[0];
  }
}

async function doWork() {
  var response = request.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/x4Nn0Tby");
  for await (c of getChunks(response)) {
    console.log(c);
  }
}
```

When I run `doWork()`, I get an error stating that the `stream` variable of `getChunks()` is not async-iterable.

*TypeError: stream is not async iterable*

This is surprising, as I thought that all readable-streams are generally async-iterable, and that the request library returns a stream when no callback is provided.  When I replace `request.get(...)` with `fs.createReadStream(...)` to some local file, all works as expected.

Perhaps the `request` library doesn't support this.  If so, what do I need to do to process HTTP response streams via async-iteration?

Using Node.js 11.13 and `request` 2.88.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some more experimenting with the `request` and `request-promise-native` libraries and don't think this is possible under the current implementation.  The resulting stream does not appear to be async-iterable at all.  Furthermore, a proper implementation will need to `await` for the response to return before processing the stream (as suggested by [@JBone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55593724/131407)).  But if you call `await request.get(...)`, you retrieve the entire contents of the response, which is undesirable for large responses.

```
const r = require("request");
const rpn = require("request-promise-native");

// contrived chunk-by-chunk stream processing 
async function* getChunks(stream) {
  for await (const chunk of stream) {
    yield chunk[0];
  }
}

async function doWork() {
  const url = "https://pastebin.com/raw/x4Nn0Tby";
  const response = r.get(url);         // returns a non-async-iterable object.
  const response2 = await rp.get(url); // returns the contents of url

  for await (c of getChunks(response)) {  // yields response not async-iterable error.
    console.log(c);
  }
}
```

My solution to this problem was to replace usage of `request` and `request-promise-native` with the `axios` library.  The libraries are functionally similar, but `axios` allows you to specify that a request should resolve to a stream; as expected, the stream is async-iterable.

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function doWork() {
  var response = await axios.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://pastebin.com/raw/x4Nn0Tby",
    responseType: "stream",
  });

  for await (c of getChunks(response.data)) {  // async-iteration over response works as expected.
    console.log(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of axios are you using?  With 0.19.0 I get `response is not async iterable`.  I couldn't find any docs indicating that axios would support this.  Any ideas?

Comment: @mattpr: I was using 0.18.0 when I wrote the sample code above.  As I recall, you need to set the response type to `stream` for this to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No, it doesn't. You might want to use a promise-based wrapper around `request`, such as [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise), which then also works with `async`/`await`.

Details: Please note that `request` has been [deprecated by its creator](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142), and hence will be discontinued. This means, that sooner or later, you will most probably need to switch to another solution, such as [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) or [needle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle), to name a few.

Of course it's up to you to evaluate these modules and figure out which best suits your needs, but my personal recommendation would be to start with `axios`, as I had very good experiences with it in the past, however, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you will have to use other alternatives just like they mentioned in the `request` module documentation that you can find here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
request supports both streaming and callback interfaces natively. If you'd like 
request to return a Promise instead, you can use an alternative interface wrapper for 
request. These wrappers can be useful if you prefer to work with Promises, or if 
you'd like to use async/await in ES2017.

Several alternative interfaces are provided by the request team, including:

request-promise (uses Bluebird Promises)
request-promise-native (uses native Promises)
request-promise-any (uses any-promise Promises)`
```

my response based on the below question:

I think you can create `async await` custom method that does it.

```
async function doMyWork() {
try {
 const response = await myOwnRequest(url); 
 } catch (e) {
   console.log ('the error', e);
 }  
}

function myOwnRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   const resp = request.get(url);
   if(resp) {
    resolve();
   } else {
     reject();
   }
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I'm not sure that I need a `Promise` returned from `request.get()` as I really just need to operate on the resulting stream (which I assumed supported await natively like `fs.createReadStream()`).  If a `Promise` is returned (via request-promise-native), then calling `await request.get(...)` resolves the entire response stream into a string.

Comment: @Steve Guildi  Please see if my updated answer can help you.

Comment: @SteveGuidi was the above (updated) answer any help? let me know if you want me to update with anything

Comment: There is a small error in myOwnRequest -- `resolve()` needs to take the object that is being returned, namely `resp`.  Otherwise, the Promise behaves as expected.  Unfortunately, the result of `request.get(...)` is just not async-iterable at all, regardless if it is returned via Promise or directly.  I ended up using the `axios` library instead, which returns streams that are async-iterable (see my answer for an example).

Answer (score 0):

The axios' stream option didn't work for me using the sample code in the above answer on axios 0.19.0.  Could be an issue between the chair and keyboard, but in any case...here is an alternative approach using `request`.

I ended up adapting request streaming to an async generator (with a buffer in between of course).
This allows a "streaming" type interface where reads and writes of the data can be interleaved...it doesn't guarantee low memory consumption.  request pipes ("pushes") to our Writable as fast as it can and there isn't a way for us to pause this or flip it into a "pull" type interface (as far as I know).  So if we are reading data out of the buffer slower than data is being written in: the buffer will get very big and memory usage will be high.

So if it is critical to keep memory usage down and you parse large files from http sources...then probably doing some monitoring/reporting on buffer size while "streaming" in order to see if you consumption code is faster or slower than the stream so you know if the buffer will get huge or stay small.  Of course if you test with a very slow http server...then all bets are off.

This could possibly be addressed by setting a fixed buffer size and making `_write` block until some more reading happens (making room in the buffer)...ie so request has to wait to write more data to the pipe.  However request may buffer internally...so this won't help with memory consumption if the data is piling up on requests' end anyway. Would have to check.

Sample code:

```
const request = require('request'),
    Writable = require('stream').Writable,
    EventEmitter = require('events');

module.exports = function (url, MAX_BYTES=1024) {
    var response = new ResponseBuffer(MAX_BYTES);

    request
        .get(url)
        .on('error', function(err) { throw err; })
        .pipe(response)
        .on('error', function(err) { throw err; });

    return response.reader();
};

class ResponseBuffer extends Writable {
    constructor (MAX_BYTES=1024) {
        super();
        this.buffer = '';
        this.open = true;
        this.done = null;  // callback to call when done reading.
        this.MAX_BYTES = MAX_BYTES;
        this.events = new EventEmitter();
    }
    _write(chunk, enc, next) {
        this.buffer += chunk;
        this.events.emit('data');
        next();
    }
    _final(done) {
        this.open = false; // signal to reader to return after buffer empty.
        return done();
    }
    async * reader () {
        while (true) {
            if (this.buffer.length == 0) {
                // buffer empty and Writable !open. return.
                if (!this.open) { return; }
                else { // buffer empty.  wait for data.
                    await new Promise(resolve => this.events.once('data', resolve));
                }
            }
            let read_bytes = this.buffer.length < this.MAX_BYTES ? this.buffer.length : this.MAX_BYTES;
            yield this.buffer.slice(0, read_bytes);
            this.buffer = this.buffer.slice(read_bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
const httpModule = require('./path/to/above/module');
var httpGen = httpModule('https://www.google.com'),
    chunk;
for await (chunk of httpGen) {
    // do something with chunk.
}
```

An alternative approach (if you are concerned about memory usage specifically) is to just download to disk (streaming to file writer) and then read incrementally off disk (you can async iter a `fs.createReadStream(...)`)